# how to apply bidirectional method when doing calculation number between integer and double value of text field in the following code?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am new to binding especially bidirectional binding. I have three text fields of quantity, price, and total. the following code from online which converted these text field into Integer and Double format for their values.

```
    StringConverter<Number> converter = new NumberStringConverter();
    StringConverter<Double> toDouble = new DoubleStringConverter();
    
    TextFormatter<Number> quantity = new TextFormatter<>(converter);
    TextFormatter<Double> price = new TextFormatter<>(toDouble);
    TextFormatter<Double> total = new TextFormatter<>(toDouble);

    Quantity.setTextFormatter(quantity);
    Price.setTextFormatter(price);
    Total.setTextFormatter(total);
    
    total.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        
        // ?????????????????????????????????????????
        
    }, quantity.valueProperty(), price.valueProperty()));
```

Please help fill out the calculation or any other way to do trigger the change whenever i enter differnt number of the text field?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Is the `total` text field editable? If so, what do you want to happen to `price` and `quantity` if `total` changes? If not, do you really need a bidirectional binding? Wouldn't a unidirectional binding (i.e. just a `Binding`) be enough? (OT: please stick to Java naming conventions; it makes your code easier to read and enables the web site to color the text appropriately.)

Comment: the total text field is not editable. what i want to do is whenever i enter certain number into quantity or price field will trigger the change of the total field. Thank you.

Comment: Then you just need `total.valueProperty().bind(...)`, not `bindBidirectional(...)` (and just return the quantity multiplied by the price).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the text field representing the total is not editable, you don't need a bidirectional binding here, just a regular binding that updates one value (the total's value) when the computed value changes.

You can do something like

```
total.valueProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
    () -> quantity.getValue() * price.getValue(),
    quantity.valueProperty(), price.valueProperty()));
```

The `Bindings.createXXXBinding(...)` methods create observable values whose values are computed (here essentially by the formula `quantity * price`). The binding expresses the fact that when the computed value changes, the value of `total` should change. A bidirectional binding expresses the idea that when either one of two values changes, the other should be set to match it. This simply won't work in this scenario, because you can't set a computed value.

From a programming perspective, this works because the `bindBidirectional()` method expects a `WritableValue` (of the appropriate type); the `Bindings.createXXXBinding()` methods return an `ObservableValue`, which is not a `WritableValue`. (By contrast, the `bind()` method only expects an `ObservableValue`.) This makes sense from a semantic perspective too: if you know the total, there's no unique way to determine the price and quantity; however if you know the price and quantity, you can determine the total. So the relationship is not symmetric.

Here's a complete working example. This can probably be improved substantially, e.g. by using `TextFormatter`s that restrict to valid entry and custom `StringConverter` implementations that use localized number formats, etc.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.DoubleStringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;


public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        TextFormatter<Integer> quantity = new TextFormatter<>(new IntegerStringConverter(), 0);
        TextFormatter<Double> price = new TextFormatter<>(new DoubleStringConverter(), 0.0);
        TextFormatter<Double> total = new TextFormatter<>(new DoubleStringConverter(), 0.0);
        
        
        
        total.valueProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                () -> quantity.getValue() * price.getValue(), 
                quantity.valueProperty(), price.valueProperty()));
        
        TextField quantityTF = new TextField("0");
        quantityTF.setTextFormatter(quantity);
        
        TextField priceTF = new TextField("0.0");
        priceTF.setTextFormatter(price);
        TextField totalTF = new TextField();
        totalTF.setEditable(false);
        totalTF.setTextFormatter(total);
        
        
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        leftCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
        ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        rightCol.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);
        root.getColumnConstraints().setAll(
                leftCol, rightCol
        );
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.setHgap(5);
        root.setVgap(5);
        root.addRow(0, new Label("Price:"), priceTF);
        root.addRow(1, new Label("Quantity:"), quantityTF);
        root.addRow(2, new Label("Total:"), totalTF);
        
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 500));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you JAMES, however, i am experience  an error The method createObjectBinding(Callable<T>, Observable...) in the type Bindings is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {}, ObjectProperty<Number>, ObjectProperty<Double>)

Comment: @KenCode Pretty sure you typed something wrong. The first argument is not `() -> {}`, it evaluates as `() -> Double`.